# Cannot create a new database in Sql Server - changed username

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I installed Sql Server on a server in a company I used to work for.

I left the company - and rejoined a year later - and now I have a different domain login.

I've logged on to the server again, and in SSMS tried to create a new database - however I get the error:

> create database permission denied in database 'master'

I have tried changing permission and adding DBCreator to BuiltInUsers and to SA - and also tried adding my new domain name to the security section - but when I try to add DBCreator to my user name, I get the error:

> Cannot alter the server role 'dbcreator' because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Is there any way I can take control of the Sql Server instance again, to allow me to create new databases?

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: Ask whoever is in charge of the instance now to give you access again.

Comment: Speak to the company DBA

Comment: Hi - there is no DBA - it was my role prior to me leaving, and now I'm back - I don't have access to my own database instance. I have access to view/update/delete in the existing databases, just not to create a new one. Thanks.

Comment: There is no DBA? So no one was in charge of it when you left? Why didn't you hand over responsibility when you left or why was it not decommissioned when you left if it wasn't going to be used any more? Something is wrong here. This, now, almost sounds like you're trying to again access to a Server you should not have access to. A company should not have a SQL Server running for a year with no knowledge of it.

Comment: I was the DBA - I did not have a replacement - but having returned after some months, I now have that responsibility again. The Sql Server instance is on a server I have full admin access to - from within my company's domain. It is not accessible outwith the company network.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Thank you @Larnu - that's resolved the issue for me. If you'd like to add an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Comment: ok - well thank you anyway, you've resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I made another SQL user which I login with, and I tried to give this user [dbcreator] grant.

I solved this via

1. runnig sql server as administrator
2. switching to my windows authentication.
3. going to folder Security -> Logins and double click on my new sql login user.
4. selecting Server roles and give grant to my user.